# How to use GetKeyDown function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm following a tutorial about health bar and mana being affected by GetKeyDown function. For some reason when I press "I" or "O" nothing occurs. Even my characters movements are immobile.

I've tried backtracking and even changing the health stats. The tutorial is from this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8StwNBJ5fE8

```
    [SerializeField]
    private Stat health;

    [SerializeField]
    private Stat mana;


    private float initHealth = 100;
    private float initMana = 50; 
    protected override void Start()
    {


        health.Initialize(initHealth, initHealth);
        mana.Initialize(initMana, initMana);

        base.Update();
    }



    private void GetInput()
    {
        direction = Vector2.zero;//reset direction 

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.I))
        {
            health.MyCurrentValue -= 10;
            mana.MyCurrentValue -= 10;

        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.O))
        {
            health.MyCurrentValue += 10;
            mana.MyCurrentValue += 10;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
            direction += Vector2.up;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            direction += Vector2.left;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            direction += Vector2.down;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {
            direction += Vector2.right;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like your function is not properly called. Never worked in Unity, but I in XNA you would have to call that `GetInput()` Function in the Update. Unity might have some level of automagic for that, but if it does that one appears to be not working.

Comment: Thank you! @Christopher The only Issue I have now is 'I' and 'O' not registering but I got my movement back thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Calling the function in the **Update()** function should produce the desired results if I am understanding your question correctly.

EDIT: Erased unnecessary response

Comment: Hi Dory, welcome to SO. Your answer does partially answer the question with the Update method. However the biggest part of your answer is about how to refactor the code. That wasn't asked and can be confusing. Please try to keep an answer focused on the problem, so that other users with a similar problem can easily find the solution. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my answer to remove the unnessecary refactoring part